# rearanging csv icw pyvis file in python

Tags: python, csv

I've a small project that is a little-bit head-breaking for me as not really a newbie in Python, i do some programming in Python for a few years in the weekend. But i see there are many ways to convert data in a csv file. I'm not sure which one to choose, and do not even really know where to start exactly, but i can do lot of research myself.

Now i have this dataset:

This is what i've got:

[image]

This is what i want:

[image]

Probably you guys know what module is the best for the given problem, currently I've my eyes on pandas and openpyxl.

Edit: It is a dataset i use to visualize with pyvis the people who met eachother, de digit is the contact count, The column is the initator, the row is the receiver of the contact
Thx in advance!

The code i have is (messy code):

```
    basepath = "/home/user/netmap/rc/"
excel_data = []
nodes = []
parsed_data = []
node_data = []
edge_data = []

def generate_parsed_data():
    global nodes
    global parsed_data
    print("parsing dataset:")
    headings = []
    excel_file = open(basepath + "db.csv")
    proof_file = open(basepath + "proof.csv", "w")
    proof_file.write("Source" + "," + "Target" + "," + "Contract count" + "," + "Role" + "," + "Family")
    proof_file.write("\n")
    for line in excel_file:
        parts = line.rstrip().split(',')
        if not headings:
            headings = parts
            continue
        for name,item in zip(headings, parts):
            if item.isdigit():
                #print('          ' + parts[0] + ',' + name + ',' + item)
                parsed_data.append(parts[0] + ',' + name + ',' + item + ',' + parts[-2] + ',' + parts[-1])
                print('      ' + parts[0] + ',' + name + ',' + item + ',' + parts[-2] + ',' + parts[-1])
                proof_file.write(parts[0] + ',' + name + ',' + item + ',' + parts[-2] + ',' + parts[-1])
                proof_file.write('\n')
                nodes.append(parts[0])
    nodes = list(dict.fromkeys(nodes))
    print(int(len(nodes))) #Hier zit het al fout

def get_contact_count(contact_name):
    tmp_list = []
    for i in parsed_data:
        par = i.rstrip().split(',')
        if par[0] == contact_name:
            tmp_list.append(par[1])
    for i in parsed_data:
        par = i.rstrip().split(',')
        if par[1] == contact_name:
            tmp_list.append(par[0])
#    print(tmp_list)
    tmp_list = list(dict.fromkeys(tmp_list))
#    print(tmp_list)
    #print(contact_name + ' has ' + str(len(tmp_list)) + ' contacts')
    return (len(tmp_list))

def generate_edge_data():
    edges_file = open(basepath + "edges.csv", "w")
    print("Tinkering edge data:")
    for e in parsed_data:
        parts = e.rstrip().split(',')
        edges_file.write(parts[0] + ',' + parts[1] + ',' + parts [2])
        print('      ' + parts[0] + ',' + parts[1] + ',' + parts [2])
        edges_file.write('\n')


def generate_node_data():
    print("tinkering node data:")
    global node_data
    nodes_file = open(basepath + "nodes.csv", "w")
    for i in parsed_data:
        parts = i.rstrip().split(',')
        contact_count = get_contact_count(parts[0])
        node_data.append(parts[0] + ',' + parts[3] + ',' + parts[4] + ',' + str(contact_count))
        print('      ' + parts[0] + ',' + parts[3] + ',' + parts[4] + ',' + str(contact_count))
    node_data = list(dict.fromkeys(node_data))
    for i in node_data:
        nodes_file.write(i)
        nodes_file.write('\n')

generate_parsed_data()
generate_node_data()
generate_edge_data()
print("Generated 3 files; edges.csv, nodes.csv & proof.csv...")
```

The code above here, is the code that  creates a file for proof, edgedata and node data. But the problem is, when i launch my pyvis script, it says there are missing nodes, I have a total of 127 nodes, only 106 are shown.

The left column is the source person, the first row is the targetpersons row. It looks like when a node/source only is targeted and initiated nothing, it will not be add to the nodes.csv

Also this one of my first python scripts i made.

Comment: Pandas is the right module

Comment: You don't need `pandas` or any other fancy module for this.  It's a simple problem.  You iterate through the lines one by one, and in each line you iterate through the columns, producing one line for each column.

Comment: Did @brb's solution help?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be complicated.  Given this program:

```
headings = []
for line in open('x.csv'):
    parts = line.rstrip().split(',')
    if not headings:
        headings = parts
        continue
    for name,item in zip(headings, parts):
        if item.isdigit():
            print(','.join((parts[0], name, item)) )
```

This input:

```
x,joe,pete,david,pascal,jonathan,george
joe,*,6,5,4,3,2
pete,1,*,4,5,2,7
david,2,3,*,6,3,2
pascal,3,,2,*,,1
jonathan,,1,,,*,,
george,1,,,,,
```

Produces this output:

```
joe,pete,6
joe,david,5
joe,pascal,4
joe,jonathan,3
joe,george,2
pete,joe,1
pete,david,4
pete,pascal,5
pete,jonathan,2
pete,george,7
david,joe,2
david,pete,3
david,pascal,6
david,jonathan,3
david,george,2
pascal,joe,3
pascal,david,2
pascal,george,1
jonathan,pete,1
george,joe,1
```

Comment: Haha thanks! Easier then i tought! but thx! I can take it from here :)

Comment: @asatru, looks like you found this post useful, would you say it's the answer? If so, please check it as the answer.

Comment: @Zach The code you gave me returns only 106 names of 127 in total, any idea why?

Comment: @asatru, that's no my code, that's Tim's. It's interesting that both your code and Tim's produce the same error that this post seems to be about: **missing rows/values**. I just added my attempt at a solution, but without the full data-set, I'm not sure we'll be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you may want to do afterwards, a pandas option may be useful.  In that case, you could simply use `melt`.  Here, I have renamed the first column `names1` but if it has another name, use that.

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'D:/'
file = 'data.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(path+file, delimiter=',')
data = data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'names1'})

df = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['names1'], var_name='names2')
df = df.dropna(subset=['value'])
df = df[df['value'] != '*']
```

[image]

Comment: You're right! Pandas is magic for multi propose :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Pandas, but I do know that you must absolutely read and write CSVs with a dedicated CSV tool.  If you do need Pandas, then use it to read and write your CSVs; using `line.split(',')` adds room for error.

Here's your data, **sample.csv**, note that I added the **PERSON** header:

```
PERSON,joe,pete,david,pascal,jonathan,george
joe,*,6,5,4,3,2
pete,1,*,4,5,2,7
david,2,3,*,6,3,2
pascal,3,,2,*,,1
jonathan,,1,,,*,
george,1,,,,,
```

Here's my attempt using Python's standard CSV library.  I'm using the **DictReader** class because it makes matches by name (person) a little easier.

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# I cannot think of these data points in terms more meaningful (and clear) than:
# - persons on the Y axis
# - persons on the X axis
# - values  on the X axis

data = defaultdict(list)


with open('sample.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)  # DictReader consumes header of X-axis persons

    # A row is many combos of "x_person and their x_val", all keyed to a y_person:
    # e.g., {pete: 6} for joe, {david: 5} for joe, etc...
    for row in reader:
        y_person = row['PERSON']

        x_persons = list(row.keys())[1:]  # [1:] to skip 'PERSON' key
        for x_person in x_persons:
            if x_person == y_person:      # the diagonal, '*'
                continue
            x_val = row[x_person]         # not checking for empty/null/None vals
            data[y_person].append([x_person, x_val])


with open('final.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for y_person, x_persons_vals in data.items():
        for x_person, x_val in x_persons_vals:
            writer.writerow([y_person, x_person, x_val])
```

Here's my output, **final.csv** (note, I didn't filter empty vals earlier, so they show up here):

```
joe,pete,6
joe,david,5
joe,pascal,4
joe,jonathan,3
joe,george,2
pete,joe,1
pete,david,4
pete,pascal,5
pete,jonathan,2
pete,george,7
david,joe,2
david,pete,3
david,pascal,6
david,jonathan,3
david,george,2
pascal,joe,3
pascal,pete,
pascal,david,2
pascal,jonathan,
pascal,george,1
jonathan,joe,
jonathan,pete,1
jonathan,david,
jonathan,pascal,
jonathan,george,
george,joe,1
george,pete,
george,david,
george,pascal,
george,jonathan,
```

If you run my code, do you get the correct number of things you are expecting?

Comment: Yes it works! i have to reshape my code now, but thanks i will give it a try again :)

Comment: It works, now i know i forgot to check if some had only "target" in the dataset

Comment: @asatru, I'm glad it's working. If any of these solutions helped, please give them an upvote; if any solution stands out as "the right answer" accept it as the answer. A good amount of work went into trying to help you.